# How to add Tooltip (dynamically) to specific dates in Bootstrap datepicker using php variables

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to add Tooltip to specific dates that they are reserved. I mean I will read my database and get reserved dates by PHP and then pass them into jQuery and add Tooltip to them. This is my code. However it doesn't work.
This code adds Tooltip just to first period of dates:

```
<?php 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT in_date,out_date FROM bookings");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $query = $db->get_results("SELECT in_date,out_date FROM bookings");

    foreach($query as $row){  
        $in_date=$row->in_date;
        $out_date=$row->out_date;
        $in_day=substr($row->in_date,-2);
        $out_day=substr($row->out_date,-2);
?>

<script>
    $('#dpbs').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        startView:1,
        weekStart: 6,
        todayBtn: true,
        language: "de",
        daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,1,2,3,4,5,6",
        datesDisabled: ['11/14/2016', '11/10/2016'],
        daysOfWeekHighlighted: "6",
        calendarWeeks: true,
        beforeShowDay: function (date){

            for (var ij = 1; ij < <?php echo json_encode($count);?>; ij++){
                if (date.getMonth() == (new Date()).getMonth())
                for(var i=<?php echo json_encode($in_day);?>;i<<?php echo json_encode($out_day);?>;i++){

                    switch (date.getDate()){
                        case i:
                        return {
                            tooltip: 'Example tooltip',
                            classes: 'active'
                        };
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        toggleActive: true
    });
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this :

```
.on('show',function(e) {
        $('td.day.activeClass').each(function(index, element) {
        var $element = $(element)
        $element.attr("title", "Promo Date");
        $element.data("container", "body");
        $element.tooltip()
      });
```

Where "activeClass" is your class, or just td.day if you want to tooltip all days!